# configure a Unity project with Fire-base

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3mi8.png)[configure a Unity project with Fire-base](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CFhK.png)
while configuration these  occurred how to solve these any idea

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.com. Generally here is not appreciated to look for how-to lessons. You will ask instead for in-depth details/help when you are stuck on a programming issue. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi Saif, I cover the process in this video: https://youtu.be/A6du3DUTIPI